# Is there a way to determine the type UFS in Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a UFS partition of unknown type. I would like to know what type of UFS it is from Linux (it could be any). Is there a tool (library) for Linux or method which can solve my problem. I know I can try to mount all types, but this message stops me:

```
>>> WARNING Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype = old
```

Tell me please  is there a safe way to mount unknown UFS type partition?

Answer (score 3):

You might run as root

```
file -s -L /dev/sda5
```

if `/dev/sda5` is the disk partition. The [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command should tell more about the data on that partition, in particular if it is some file system data.

One you know more about that partition, you could mount it in a safer way. BTW, I would mount it as read-only first.

Comment: Thanks. "file -s -L /dev/sda5" is the method. It perfectly detecet ufs2. Now I`ll try to detect others.  And one more thing. Does read-only mount is safe way in any case?

Comment: I`ll accept the answer after some test. I`ll try to detect some other UFS partitions. I want to make sure that this method is universal. It`s seems to me fair.

Comment: My example filesystem had an MBR at the start.  I got: `DOS/MBR boot sector, BSD disklabel`.

Comment: It turns out `file` has a `-k` parameter, which allows it to keep looking for other matches.